# Navigation component with bottom nav always creates new fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

Is it possible to make my Navigation component not create new fragment (but use existing one) when clicked on bottom nav item ?

I want to use only navigation component.

```
binding.bottomNavBar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.currentWeatherFragment -> {
                navController.popBackStack(R.id.currentWeatherFragment, false)
                return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

            R.id.futureListWeatherFragment -> {
                if (futureNumber > 0) {
                    Log.d("test", "popbackstack")
                    navController.popBackStack(R.id.futureListWeatherFragment, false)
                } else {
                    navController.navigate(navController.graph.findNode(R.id.futureListWeatherFragment)!!.id)
                    futureNumber++
                    Log.d("test", "navigate")
                }
                return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

            R.id.settingsFragment -> {
                if (settingsNumber > 0) {
                    navController.popBackStack(R.id.settingsFragment, false)
                } else {
                    navController.navigate(navController.graph.findNode(R.id.settingsFragment)!!.id)
                    settingsNumber++
                }
                return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

        }
        false
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with `use existing one` fragment? Use same fragment for all navigation items? Or just create fragments once and not create them again after navigation changes?

Comment: Create fragments once and not create them again

Comment: Guess it is because of `navController.popBackStack`. Did you try to use some [navigate](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController.html#navigate\(int\)) method instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is not possible for now. Since navigation component is still in a beta stage, unfortunately it lacks the ability to adapt to all cases.

One solution would be to keep all your data in a viewmodel, and use this data each time navcontroller creates a new instance of the fragment. This way, you can hold on to the data you have already fetched. Plus, your business logic will be separated from your UI logic, so your data can also survive configuration changes.

More information on Viewmodels [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?gclid=Cj0KCQiA5NPjBRDDARIsAM9X1GLYJpqlmNvYDUD5KQSMACMPtwacE_6-X-01MwEQmRLxld17nTQxJosaAqE1EALw_wcB)

Comment: I am using ViewModels, and the problem for me is with the state of the fragment, not with the data.

Comment: It's not beta. It's RC1